# liminf and limsup properties

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

First we introduce the following notation:
$$ 
\mathcal{N}_\infty:= \{N\subset \mathbb{N}| \mathbb{N} \text{\ }N \text{ is finite}\}
$$
and
$$ 
\mathcal{N}_\infty^\#:= \{N\subset \mathbb{N}| N \text{ is infinite}\}
$$
In most textbooks of real analysis, the limit inferior is defined in one of the following two ways:
$$
\liminf_n C_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{m=n}^\infty C_m
$$
or
$$
\liminf_n C_n = \left\{x \in \mathcal{X} | x\in C_k \text{ ultimately for all } k \right\}
$$
We need to show that:
$$
\liminf_n C_n = \bigcap_{N\in \mathcal{N}_\infty^\#} \overline{\bigcup_{n\in N}C_n}
$$
where the overline denotes the set closure in the respective topology. For the limit superior we need to show that:
$$
\limsup_n C_n = \bigcap_{N\in \mathcal{N}_\infty} \overline{\bigcup_{n\in N}C_n}
$$
These properties appear in [p.110, 1] as [exercises](http://books.google.com/books?id=8ujVd_aeKygC&pg=PA110).

[1] R.T. Rockafellar and R. J-B. Wets, "Variational Analysis", Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften, vol. 317, 1998.

Comment: there is already a very similar question. maybe they should be merged

Comment: @Glougloubarbaki : If you know a very similar question perhaps you should post it here.

Comment: @Pantelis : What have you tried?

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I have tried showing that the one set is included in the other. But I don't see how I should proceed.

Comment: It’s not true as stated. Take $C_n=\{1/m:m\ge n\}$; then by your definition $\liminf_n C_n=\varnothing$, but $0\in\bigcap_{N\in\mathcal{N}_\infty^\#} \overline{\bigcup_{n\in N} C_n}$. You need closures in your original definitions as well.

Comment: I've posted a similar comment to several questions related to this one, but I'll add it here anyway, since it might be relevant. [Definition 5.2.1](http://books.google.cl/books?id=GCKBqSYgUp0C&pg=PA145) and [Proposition 5.2.2](http://books.google.cl/books?id=GCKBqSYgUp0C&pg=PA146) in Beer: Topologies on closed and closed convex sets seems to be a more general version of this. (He works with nets instead of sequences.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak : I see that proposition 5.2.2. in Beer is exactly what I want to show. But I can't access the definition on Google Books. Could you please cite it here?

Comment: @Pantelis: I see that you've already posted some answer, so you probably don't need them anymore, but here are the relevant pages from Beer's book - for the people that cannot view them at google books.
(I hope uploading 3 pages - which are available at google books anyway - qualifies as a fair use.)
145: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BVJNA.png
146: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YUJ4x.png
147: http://i.stack.imgur.com/iZGW9.png

Comment: [Related answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85745/6179).

Comment: Pantelis: This (accepted) answer of yours and the text of the question itself both contain some serious inaccuracy which was mentioned by @Brian. Similar problems were pointed to you [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85745/6179) and you acknowledged them, if I understand you correctly. I suggest you mention this fact somewhere in the present question and answer, instead of letting people believe otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Martin Sleziak (for pointing at the book of G. Beer [p.145, Prop. 5.2.2. in 1]) the proof is as follows:

**Proposition 1.** Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{T})$ be a Hausdorff topological space. Then:
$$
\liminf_n C_n = \bigcup_{N\in\mathcal{N}_\infty^\#}\overline{\bigcap_{v\in N}C_v}
$$

*Proof.*

(1). Let $x\in\liminf_n C_n$ and let $\Sigma\in\mathcal{N}_\infty^\#$. Let $W$
be a neighborhood of $x$. There is a $N_0\in\mathbb{N}$ sucht that for all $n\geq N_0$
such that $n\in\Sigma$:
$$
W\cap C_n \neq \emptyset
$$
Thus,
$$
x\in\overline{\bigcup_{n\in\Sigma}C_n}
$$
(2). Assume that $x\notin \liminf_n C_n$. Then, there is an 
open neighborhood of $x$, let $W\ni x$, such that 
$\Sigma_0:=\{n\in\mathbb{N}| W\cap C_n = \emptyset\}$. Therefore,
$x\notin \overline{\bigcup_{n\in\Sigma_0}C_n}$. This completes the
proof. $\square$

**Note 1:** Characterization of the closure of a set: Let $C\subset \mathcal{X}$ and $\bar{C}$ denote its closure which is defined as:

$$
\bar{C}=\bigcap\{F\supset C| F^c\in \mathcal{T}\}
$$
Then:

$$
x\in\bar{C} \Leftrightarrow \forall V\in\mathcal{T},\ V\ni x:\ V\cap C \neq \emptyset
$$

**Note 2:** This result is stated in [1] for nets of sets in $\mathcal{X}$, $\{C_n\}_{n\in\Lambda}$ where $\Lambda$ is a partially ordered set. Then the class $\mathcal{N}_\infty^\#$ is replaced by the family of cofinal sets of $\Lambda$. Set set $\Sigma$ is called a cofinal subset of $\Lambda$ if for all $\lambda\in\Lambda,\ \exists\sigma\in\Sigma:\ \sigma\geq\lambda$.

**Corollary 2.** Let $\{C_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of subsets of $\mathcal{X}$. Then:
$$
\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_n \subseteq \overline{\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}C_n} \subseteq \liminf_n C_n
$$

*Proof.* It follows from Proposition 1 taking $N=\mathbb{N}\in\mathcal{N}_\infty^\#$. $\square$

[1] G. Beer, "Topologies on Closed and Closed Convex Sets", Kluwer Academic Publishers, ISBN: 0-7923-2531-1.

Comment: You should notice that the definition from Beer is - in the case of sequences - the following: $x\in\liminf A_n$ $\Leftrightarrow$ every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $A_n$ for all but finitely many $n$'s\\
$x\in\limsup A_n$ $\Leftrightarrow$ every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects $A_n$ for infinitely many $n$'s\\
This is the same as your definition if you work with discerete topology.

Comment: @MartinSleziak This is easy to prove the two definitions to be equivalent I mentioned (by the way, I found the book), i.e. in a topological space $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{T})$ let $\mho(x)$ be the family of open neighborhoods of $x$. Then $\liminf_n C_n = \{x|\forall V\in\mho(x),\ \exists N\in \mathcal{N}_\infty,
\forall n\in N: C_n\cap V\neq \emptyset\}$. Equivalently: $\liminf_n C_n = \{x|\forall V\in\mho(x),\ \exists N_0\in \mathbb{N},
\forall n\geq N_0: C_n\cap V\neq \emptyset\}$.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the overline you put shouldn't be there ; it has no reason to be. I'll prove what you want to prove without putting it there to prove my point.

I'll do the $\liminf$ case for you, the $\limsup$ case is symmetric. You want to show that
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{m =n}^{\infty} C_m \right) 
= 
\bigcap_{N \in \mathcal N_{\infty}^{\#}} \left( \bigcup_{n \in N} C_n \right).
$$
You were right wanting to say that you want to prove $(\subseteq)$ and $(\supseteq)$, but you can make your life more easier a little. To show that
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{m =n}^{\infty} C_m \right)
\subseteq
\bigcap_{N \in \mathcal N_{\infty}^{\#}} \left( \bigcup_{n \in N} C_n \right),
$$
you only need to show that 
$$
\forall N \in \mathcal N_{\infty}^{\#}, \qquad 
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{m =n}^{\infty} C_m \right)
\subseteq 
\bigcup_{n \in N} C_n  
$$
since being in the intersection means being in all of the things you intersect over. Now suppose
$$
x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{m =n}^{\infty} C_m \right) \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \exists n \, \text{ s.t. } x \in \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} C_m \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad \forall m \ge n, \quad x \in C_m.
$$
Since $N$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb N$, there exists $m \ge n$ with $m \in N$. Therefore there exists $m \in N$ such that 
$$
x \in C_m \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in N} C_n,
$$
hence we are done with this part.

It's just manipulations of large symbols, don't be astonished by the length of the proof. To show that 
$$
\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \bigcap_{m =n}^{\infty} C_m \right)
\supseteq
\bigcap_{N \in \mathcal N_{\infty}^{\#}} \left( \bigcup_{n \in N} C_n \right),
$$
You can restrict yourself to show that
$$
x \in \bigcap_{N \in \mathcal N_{\infty}^{\#}} \left(  \bigcup_{n \in N} C_n \right) \quad \Longrightarrow \quad \exists n \, \text{ s.t. } \,  x \in \bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty} C_m.
$$
Consider the set $N_X = \{ m \in \mathbb N \, | \, x \notin C_m \}$. If $N_X \in \mathcal N_{\infty}^{\#}$, we have
$$
x \in \bigcap_{N \in \mathcal N_{\infty}^{\#}} \left( \bigcup_{m \in N} C_m \right) \qquad \Longrightarrow \qquad x \in \bigcup_{m \in N_X} C_m,
$$
but this is a contradiction because $x$ is (by definition of $N_X$) not in any of those $C_m$'s. Thus $N_X \in N_{\infty}$, and therefore there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that for all $m \ge n$, $x \in C_m$. This completes the argument.

Hope that helps,